# Tentative definition of struct with incomplete type

Tags: c, language-lawyer, c11

Consider the following as a C file:

```
static struct S a;

int main() {
  return (long)&a;
}

struct S {
  int b;
} s;
```

Based on my reading of the [C11 spec](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), I believe this is undefined behavior. 6.9.2 states:

> A declaration of an identifier for an object that has file scope without an initializer, and without a storage-class specifier or with the storage-class specifier static, constitutes a tentative definition.

and under a Semantics heading (not Constraints):

> If the declaration of an identifier for an object is a tentative definition and has internal linkage, the declared type shall not be an incomplete type.

It seems that the declaration on the first line is a tentative definition, and that the object `a` has internal linkage, and yet `struct S` has incomplete type at the time of the declaration. So, I would expect this to violate the second quotation, thus resulting in undefined behavior.

However, GCC does not print any diagnostic when run with the `--std=c11 -Wall -pedantic` flags. Am I misunderstanding the standard, or does GCC not print a diagnostic for this type of undefined behavior?

Comment: FWIW clang generates the following warning: *"warning: tentative definition of variable with internal linkage has incomplete non-array type 'struct S' [-Wtentative-definition-incomplete-type]"*

Comment: GCC tries to produce a reasonable result rather than reject code, though `-pedantic -std=c11` limits what it will accept.  The address of `a` in the program shown doesn't need to depend on the type (and hence size) of `a`; this might be part of why you get away with it.  Does anything change if you add a function that accesses `a` after the structure type is completed (and call that function)? However, this is definitively not an answer — it is just casual observations.

Comment: Aside: `(long)&a;` is UB if the address does not fit in a `long`.

Comment: In general UB doesn't require a diagnostic. In hindsight this case probably should have been specified as implementation-defined

Comment: the posted code causes the `gcc` compiler to output the warning message: "...:4:10: warning: conversion to ‘int’ from ‘long int’ may alter its value [-Wconversion]"

Comment: @chux Not UB but implementation-defined behavior. 6.3.2.3/5.

Comment: @Lundin Looks like potential UB still.  C11 6.3.2.3/5 is about integer to `*`.  /6 is about `*` to integer which has "If the result cannot be represented in the integer type,
the behavior is undefined." as suggest by [if the address does not fit in a long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49863878/tentative-definition-of-struct-with-incomplete-type?noredirect=1#comment86743718_49863878)

Comment: @user3386109 The warning sounds like if it would be an incomplete array type the behavior would be well-defined... But it is UB in either case, isn't?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Do you know any real use-case of a tentative definition of an identifier with external linkage having incomplete type? For now it is difficult to imagine something useful.

Comment: @SomeName: Offhand, I can't think of a real use-case for a tentative definition of an identifier with external linkage having an incomplete type.  I expect it happens; a possible cause could be automatically generated code.  But I haven't got anything to point at.

Comment: @SomeName That's actually a good language lawyer question (assuming it hasn't been asked yet). Be sure to get a copy of the C11 draft specification (OP posted a link, or search for N1570). And read the full text of section 6.9.2, especially the example in paragraph 5. As far as I can tell, the tentative definition of an incomplete array *is* well defined.

Comment: @user3386109 The array in the example you mentioned has external linkage so I agree about it is well-defined. Actually I have never thought that we could write something like that and it looks a bit confusing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes this is undefined.

Undefined behavior is just what the term indicates, it is not defined by the standard. Any compiler may add its own definitions and thereby extend the standard, and is not obliged to diagnose any of them. In particular, gcc has some special ideas about tentative definitions. Code that uses these is not portable.

Comment: Re. the non-static objects, could you post a link that explains them or an example or two. They sound bad, which is why I've probably never used them and, thus, am not sure what they are. At a _guess_, could this be doing: `static int foo; extern int foo;` at file scope???

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked the `static` you had in your tentative definition.